# Should the same hreflang localization links be repeated under the <loc> for different languages in an XML sitemap?

Tags: seo, sitemap, xml-sitemap, hreflang, technical-seo

So I know that alternative links should be put like the below in a sitemap...

```
<url>
<loc>http://www.mywebsite.com/lang/french/</loc>
<xhtml:link 
             rel="alternate"
             hreflang="fr"
             href="http://www.mywebsite.com/lang/french/"
             />
<xhtml:link 
             rel="alternate"
             hreflang="en-us"
             href="http://www.mywebsite.com/lang/us/"
             />
<xhtml:link 
             rel="alternate"
             hreflang="en"
             href="http://www.mywebsite.com/"
             />
```

In the above example the `fr` version is the `<loc>`.
Do I also need to create a `en` and `en-us` block with `fr` and `en` / `en-us` as alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

Ok so after some more research it seem you do have to repeat yourself.
Found at here.. https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions#sitemap

Example...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/english/page.html</loc>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de"
               href="http://www.example.com/deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de-ch"
               href="http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="en"
               href="http://www.example.com/english/page.html"/>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/deutsch/page.html</loc>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de"
               href="http://www.example.com/deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de-ch"
               href="http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="en"
               href="http://www.example.com/english/page.html"/>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/page.html</loc>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de"
               href="http://www.example.com/deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de-ch"
               href="http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="en"
               href="http://www.example.com/english/page.html"/>
  </url>
</urlset>
```